# Увеличение производительности BufferedReader

Tags: java

Изучая класс Reader я наткнулся на следующее определение: "BufferedReader считывает текст из символьного потока ввода, буферизируя прочитанные символы. Использование буфера призвано увеличить производительность чтения данных из потока".

Вопрос: каким образом использование буфера увеличивает производительность, по сравнению с использованием обычных ридеров?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Обычные" (т.е. не обёрнутые в `BufferedReader`) ридеры за каждым чтением символов обращаются к источнику (например, файлу), что является относительно затратным по времени делом. Например, у вас есть файл, содержащий в себе довольно много символов, и вы хотите посимвольно прочитать его при помощи обычного `FileReader`. В таком случае каждый ваш вызов метода `read()`, читающий один отдельный символ, будет порождать обращение к файлу, и вы обратитесь к нему столько раз, сколько в нём имеется символов.

А `BufferedReader` же работает таким образом, что он обращается к источнику, считывает оттуда сразу много символов (по умолчанию 8192), занося их в определённый массив, и при следующих вызовах методов `read()` или `readLine()` символы будут читаться из этого массива, что конечно же намного быстрее.

Так что если вы захотите посимвольно прочитать текстовый файл, но уже с использованием `BufferedReader`, то при первом вызове метода `read()` сразу 8192 символа будет буферизовано, и при следующих вызовах метода символы просто будут браться из буфера.

Замерим время чтения текстового документа, состоящего примерно из ста тысяч символов, без использования `BufferedReader` и с ним.

Без использования `BufferedReader`:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("sometxt.txt")) {
    int i;
    do {
        i = fileReader.read();
    } while (i != -1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

Результат:

```
Time: 428
```

А теперь с использованием `BufferedReader`:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sometxt.txt"))) {
    int i;
    do {
        i = bufferedReader.read();
    } while (i != -1);
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

Результат:

```
Time: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Как [написано в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#:%7E:text=Without%20buffering%2C%20each%20invocation%20of,DataInputStream%20with%20an%20appropriate%20BufferedReader.):

> In general, each read request made of a `Reader` causes a corresponding read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream. It is therefore advisable to wrap a `BufferedReader` around any `Reader` whose `read()` operations may be costly, such as FileReaders and InputStreamReaders. ...
>
> Without buffering, each invocation of `read()` or `readLine()` could cause bytes to be read from the file, converted into characters, and then returned, which can be very inefficient.

То есть, буферизация нужна, чтобы избежать побайтового/посимвольного чтения с диска или из сети -- в процессе чтения данные загружаются в буфер в памяти, и читаются уже оттуда, сокращая таким образом количество обращений к диску/сети.  Поэтому данный класс и рекомендуется использовать для оборачивания экземпляров `FileReader` / `InputStreamReader`.